# Conjugate gradient with two preconditioners of different dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, conjugate-gradient

I need to estimate $\mathbf{y}$ defined as:
$$ \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{P}\mathbf{B}^T(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{P}\mathbf{B}^T+\mathbf{R})^{-1} \mathbf{x}, $$
with $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ two diagonal matrices with positive entries.
I want to implement the multiplication by the matrix inverse using a preconditioned conjugate gradient method, since I can find a good preconditioner in that case and the size of the matrices prevent a direct computation of the solution. However, I know (thanks to the Matrix Cookbook) that this expression can be rewritten as:
$$ \mathbf{y} = (\mathbf{P}^{-1}+ \mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{R}^{-1} \mathbf{B})^{-1} \mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{R}^{-1} \mathbf{x}, $$
Again, I can apply preconditioned conjugate gradient to compute the matrix inversion since I have a decent preconditioner at my disposal in this case as well.

My question is straightforward: Is there a method for finding $\mathbf{y}$  (typically a scheme based on conjugate gradient) able to benefit from the insignts of the two preconditioners at the same time ?

I am aware of the multipreconditioned conjugate gradient method (which is related to the block conjugate gradient method) but it is unfortunately not valid here. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.